# Change UserControl property using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, user-controls

I have my `UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomCtrl.MyButton">
   <Button x:Name="Btn" />
</UserControl>
```

And I use my `UserControl` in a `Window`

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <MyButton Background="Aqua" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to change the `Background` property of the Button `Btn` using the property `Background` of my `UserControl` **with XAML**.

I tried adding the `Background` property

```
public class MyButton: UserControl
{
    public new Brush Background
    {
        get
        { return Btn.GetValue(BackgroundProperty) as Brush; }

        set
        { Btn.SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value); }
    }        
}
```

But it has no effect.
Instead if I use the code `MyButtonControl.Background = Brushes.Aqua;`, it works.
Why? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3182776/1380428

Comment: If a button is the only thing you have in your user control, then it seems to me that you're just trying to add functionality to the button (or potentially change its look). Either way, it'd be easier to extend the button class (or change it template).

Answer (score 1):

The `UserControl.Background` is *taken*, `UserControls` are not custom controls and you have no control over how this propery is used. If you want to change the background of just one control you can expose a new dependency property and bind it to the `Button.Background`.

Comment: A code snippet example would have been really helpful here. :(

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have two choices:

1. The easy way, simply set the "Btn" Background to Transparent like so:

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="CustomCtrl.MyButton">
         <Button x:Name="Btn" Background="Transparent"/>
   </UserControl>
   ```
2. another way is to bind the background color of the button to the background color of the control:

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="CustomCtrl.MyButton" x:Name="control">
         <Button x:Name="Btn" Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=control}"/>
   </UserControl>
   ```

Tested both and seem to work.

Comment: These way may not work if the UserControl and the Button have differents borders. I want to change only the Button Background using the UserControl Background property.

Comment: If I understand correctly, with all these limitations, you might need to do what you ask by code behind or by behavior. assuming the Btn is public

Answer (score 0):

With

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <MyButton Background="Aqua" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

you are setting the background color of the `UserControl`. To set the background color of the `Button` you have to

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomCtrl.MyButton">
   <Button x:Name="Btn" Background="Aqua" />
</UserControl>
```

Edit (after OP comment): You cannot modify the `UserControl.Background`, but a new property works:

```
public Brush ButtonBackground {
    get {
        return this.Btn.Background;
    }
    set {
        this.Btn.Background = value;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <MyButton ButtonBackground="Aqua" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I know, but, as I wrote, I want to change the `Background` of the Button `Btn`, using the UserControl `Background` property. I don't want to change the XAML of my UserControl, i want to change only the XAML where there is the Window.